# How do I silence the "itunes needs to check for an update to the carrier settings for your iPad" message?

Tags: ios, ipad

I no longer use a cellular connection on my iPad. I am quite content with WiFi.

For this or some other reason, I am getting

```
itunes needs to check for an update to the carrier settings for your iPad
```

[image: itunes needs to check for an update to the carrier settings for your iPad]

How do I silence this message?

iOS 9.0.2

Comment: What happens if you Check?

Comment: Nothing! But the message will return when iTunes is relaunched. OS X and iOS used to have an unwritten "Thou shall not pester thy users" rule. This is one recent example of their move away from this doctrine.

Comment: I get this maddening window every time too, whether I check or not. I hope someone figures this out.

Answer (score 1):

To silence this message follow its instructions:

> Go to the Advanced pane of iTunes preferences and turn on “Check for new software updates automatically”.